# How to select a value that can come from two different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, liquibase

First, SQL is not my strength. So I need help with the following problem. I'll simplify the table contents to describe the problem.

Let's start with three tables : `table1` with columns `id_1` and `value`, `table2` with columns `id_2` and `value`, and `table3` with columns `id_3` and `value`. As you'll notice, a field `value` appears in all three tables, while ids have different column names. **Modifying column names is not an option** because they are used by Java legacy code.

I need to set `table3.value` using `table1.value` or `table2.value` according to the fields `table1.id_1`, `table2.id_2` and `table3.id_3`.

My last attempt, which describes what I try to do, is the following:

```
UPDATE table3
    SET value=(IF ((SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id_1=id_3) > 0)
                 SELECT value FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id_1=id_3
              ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_2=id_3)) > 0)
                 SELECT value FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_2=id_3)
```

Here are some informations about the tables and the update.

1. This update will be included in an XML file used by Liquibase.
2. It must work with **Oracle** or **SQL Server**.
3. An id from `table3.id_3` can be found at most once in `table1.id_1` or in `table2.id_2`, but not in both tables simultaneously.
4. If `table3.id_3` is not found in `table1.id_1` nor in `table2.id_2`, `table3.value` remains null.

As you can imagine, my last attempt failed. In that case, the `IF` command was not recognized during the Liquibase update. If anyone has any ideas how to deal with this, I'd appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `Oracle` very well, but a `SQL Server` approach would be the following using [`COALESCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.110).aspx) and [`OUTER JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)s.

```
Update      T3
Set         Value = Coalesce(T1.Value, T2.Value)
From        Table3  T3
Left Join   Table2  T2  On  T3.Id_3 = T2.Id_2
Left Join   Table1  T1  On  T3.Id_3 = T1.Id_1
```

The [`COALESCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.110).aspx) will return the first non-`NULL` value from the [`LEFT JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) to tables `1` and `2`, and if a record was not found in either, it would be set to `NULL`.

Comment: COALESE() function works in Oracle the same way. This should solve existing problem. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

Comment: Since OP wants it to remain `NULL` if not found in T1 or T2 I'd add `''`that to the coalesce, no? Or `CASE` it. But definitly how it should be done is with coalesce!

Comment: @SergeiPodlipaev Yes, but I'm not sure if the `UPDATE` syntax is the same.  Though, the question states `SQL Server` *or* `Oracle`, so I would assume either implementation would suffice.

Comment: @scsimon Adding `NULL` to `COALESCE()` is not needed.  If all arguments are `NULL`, the result will be `NULL`.

Comment: Got ya, i was thinking ''

Comment: @Siyual you are quite right! Joins are not supported in Oracle SQL syntax. Still it can be done with merge operation.

Comment: @SergeiPodlipaev - Huh? joins not supported in Oracle SQL? Since when?

Comment: @mathguy I don't see a problem with using two `JOIN`s in an update statement.  It's a very efficient way of pulling the data needed for the `UPDATE`, and as long as the tables are properly indexed, it won't be an issue.

Comment: @Siyual - Joins are expensive operations, and triple joins are even more expensive. If you use a `union all` between tables 1 and 2 instead of a `join` between them the solution should be more efficient. As I suggested to the OP in my answer, he should check the different solutions to see what works best for him, but in principle that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

It is Siyual's `UPDATE` written with `MERGE` operator.

```
MERGE into table_1
USING (
SELECT COALESCE(t2.value, t3.value) as value, t1.id_1 as id
FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3
WHERE t2.id_2 = t3.id_3 and t1.id_1 = t2.id_2
) t on (table_1.id_1 = t.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET table_1.value = t.value
```

This should work in Oracle.

Comment: You need to write "merge INTO table_1....." (at least in Oracle and in the SQL standard). Also, the join of all three tables seems excessive for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle

```
UPDATE table3 t
SET value=COALESCE((SELECT value FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id_1=t.id_3),
                   (SELECT value FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_2=t.id_3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your assumption #3, you can use `union all` to put together tables 1 and 2 without running the risk of duplicating information (at least for the id's of interest). So a simple `merge` solution like the one below should work (in all DB products that implement the `merge` operation).

```
merge into table3
  using (
          select id_2 as id, value from table2 
          union all 
          select id_3, value from table 3
  ) t
  on table3.id_3 = t.id
when matched
then update set table3.value = t.value;
```

You may want to test the various solutions and see which is most effective for your specific tables.

(**Note**: `merge` should be more efficient than the `update` solution using `coalesce`, at least when relatively few of the id's in table3 have a match in the other tables. This is because the `update` solution will re-insert NULL where NULL was already stored when there is no match. The `merge` solution avoids this unnecessary activity.)